# selenium parsing html with multiple chiclets

Tags: python, html, selenium

I need to get a list/array of title elements (menu1,menu2...) from the following html structure. This a page with multiple clickable icons, and each icon leads to separate sites:

```
<div style>
    <div class = "whole-menu">
        <div ID = "menus">
            <div class = "menu">
                <a href="http://mymenu.net" target="_blank" title="menu1" >..</a>
            </div>
            <div class = "menu">
                <a href="http://mymenu2.net" target="_blank" title="menu2" >..</a>
            </div>
            <div class = "menu">...</div>
             .
             .
```

My attempts:

```
br.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
```

or

```
br.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="menus"]/a/div')
```

returns blank or something like:

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="72da797dc298fb314fbefb440957764c", element="0.7504794419530361-1")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="72da797dc298fb314fbefb440957764c", element="0.7504794419530361-2")>
```

Comment: Based on the HTML you pasted, I don't see any elements with class value of "service". Maybe you meant to put '//*[@class="menus"]/a/div'?

Comment: @RyanGriffin : Thanks for pointing out, I meant "menus". Corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually your code should return list of web-elements (like `<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement(session="72da797dc298fb314fbefb440957764c", element="0.7504794419530361-1")>`). This is correct behavior.

If you need to get `title` attribute from each anchor:

```
titles = [element.get_attribute('title') for element in br.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="menu"]/a')]
```